# Trouble parsing easy xml array with restsharp

Tags: arrays, deserialization, restsharp

New to restsharp and C#, but after 3 days of research I'm at an impasse, and can find no information online which has helped me.

This should be an easy task. I need to parse xml containing an array of message, similar to this:

```
 <HopXmlApi xsi:schemaLocation="http://whatever.whatever.com/api   
 http://whatever.whatever.com/api/xmlapi.xsd" state="ok" timestamp="1379607238995" 
  result-size="1" server-version="4.4.3-46665">
      <success>
        <request>UPDATE_DB</request>
        <message>Database updated successfully</message>
        <message>5271601000</message>
        <message>NetD, NetA, cB-EndZone, cS-Fare</message>
      </success>
    </HopXmlApi>
```

I've tried a million different retrieval classes. Right now have this:

```
class mess
{

        public string success { get; set; }
        public string request { get; set; }
        public List<message> Value { get; set; }
}

    public class message
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Trying to parse with:

```
    var x = new RestSharp.Deserializers.XmlDeserializer();
    mess xid = x.Deserialize<mess>(response);
```

What I return are a parsed string for request ('UPDATE DB'), string for request
is just every element shoved together as noted below.

and array of 1 string element for 'Value' which is the same as the 'request' tag:

> UPDATE_DBDatabase updated successfully5271601000NSDNet, UGN, cB-GreenZone, cS-Fairfield

I have tried everything and I can only get this type of result, or 1 string for Value (the first element -'Database Updated Successfully'), or an array saying 'Count=0'.

Completely lost at this point, and I'm sure I'm making a very basic error. Hoping someone can shed some light on this for me.